# Laravel: image don't display with cover

Tags: laravel, image, display, cover

I'm currently developing a project in laravel based on studies, but I'm having some difficulties with displaying a profile picture. The upload is done correctly, the image is uploaded to the server and also to the database, however, it is still not displayed in my application, always returning an image link not found.

```
 if(!empty(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->cover) &&
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::exists(public_path() . '/storage/' . \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->cover)){
        $cover = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->url_cover;
    } else {
        $cover = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->url_cover;
    }
```

```
 <aside class="dash_sidebar">
        <article class="dash_sidebar_user">
            <img class="dash_sidebar_user_thumb" src="{{ $cover }}" alt="" title=""/>

            <h1 class="dash_sidebar_user_name">
                <a href="{{ route('admin.users.edit', ['user' => \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id]) }}">{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->name }}</a>
            </h1>
```

I already tried the command php artisan storage:link but without success. My .env configuration is correct too.

Comment: Not related to your question, but you can add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` and `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;` at the top of your file, and reduce your code to `if (!empty(Auth::user()->cover && File::exists(...))`, or use the `auth()` helper, like `auth()->user()`. I'd go insane if I had to type the fully-qualified namespace every time  For your question, typically, you use the `asset()` helper to display images from URL, like `src="{{ asset($cover) }}"`, but it also partially depends what `url_cover` contains.